# Excel Formula to reference Master Sheet

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I currently have a master excel sheet that has the names of about 20 different sales people, and a new row is created, with the salesmen name in column A, whenever they make a sale. But, I now want this data to be available to the salesmen, but I want only them to only be able to view their info, not everyones. So, I am going to create 20 different individual files, one for each salesman.

Is there a formula that I can use for these 20 different spreadsheets to update for that specific salesmen every time I update the master sheet?

Comment: Of course with a vlookup you can return the values of each salesman like in this link: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html

Comment: Create a master sheet

Comment: Rather than creating 20 different workbooks, you could just create sheets in your `Main` workbook and hide the sheets. You can than display the sheet for logged in user. This way all your data stays in 1 workbook and your formulas become a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

You could create workbooks from a Column (Looping from row 1 to x) based on unique values.

So for each unique salesmen in Column A you create a new workbook. Then you only need to use your current Master file, and do whatever you want in that file. When you want to send a sheet to a sales person, you execute the code and Excel will copy all rows that belongs to the specific sales man and create 20 individual sheets for you which you can send.

**Process:**

I have a file in a folder, which I have all my main data.

[image]

The main data looks like this, and the new workbooks will be named after Column A. It will only create workbook for unique names.

[image]

After running the macro it has create the following 5 new workbooks.

[image]

This is how Workbook "Anne - 10-27-18,14.24.47.xlsx" looks like:

[image]

This is how Workbook "Belle- 10-27-18,14.24.47.xlsx" looks like:

[image]

[I used the following code and only modified to make it dynamic of the unique list column. All credit to J. Fox at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368771/how-to-create-a-new-workbook-for-each-unique-value-in-a-column)

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportByName()
'Source and Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368771/how-to-create-a-new-workbook-for-each-unique-value-in-a-column

Dim unique(1000) As String 'How many unique values we can store
Dim wb(1000) As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, y As Long, ct As Long, uCol As Long, ColName As Long
Dim StaticDate As Date

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Your main worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Column Where Unique Names are
ColName = 1

uCol = 12 'End column of data in MainFile


ct = 0

'get a unique list of users
For x = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColName).End(xlUp).Row
    If CountIfArray(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, ColName), unique()) = 0 Then
        unique(ct) = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, ColName).Text
        ct = ct + 1
    End If
Next x

StaticDate = Now() 'This create the same timestamp for all the new workbooks

'loop through the unique list
For x = 0 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColName).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    If unique(x) <> "" Then
        'add workbook
        Set wb(x) = Workbooks.Add

        'copy header row
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, uCol)).Copy wb(x).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)

        'loop to find matching items in ws and copy over
        For y = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColName).End(xlUp).Row
            If ws.Cells(y, ColName) = unique(x) Then

                'copy full formula over
                'ws.Range(ws.Cells(y, 1), ws.Cells(y, uCol)).Copy wb(x).Sheets(1).Cells(WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb(x).Sheets(1).Columns(uCol)) + 1, 1)

                'to copy and paste values
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(y, 1), ws.Cells(y, uCol)).Copy
                wb(x).Sheets(1).Cells(WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb(x).Sheets(1).Columns(uCol)) + 1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

            End If
        Next y

        'autofit
        wb(x).Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit

        'save when done
        wb(x).SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & unique(x) & " - " & Format(StaticDate, "mm-dd-yy, hh.mm.ss") & ".xlsx"
        wb(x).Close SaveChanges:=True

    Else
        'once reaching blank parts of the array, quit loop
        Exit For
    End If

Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ErrHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Public Function CountIfArray(lookup_value As String, lookup_array As Variant)
CountIfArray = Application.Count(Application.Match(lookup_value, lookup_array, 0))
End Function
```