# Adding 1 to each row without using for loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for an easy way to add a certain number to each row in a column. Something like `range("b1:b9")=range("a1:a9")+1`

> From this:

[image]

> to this:

[image]

Comment: Just a note on performance, using the Built-In functions such as `Selection.PasteSpecial` are fast for small datasets, if you go over say 100k rows then reconsider the performance of a For-Loop.

Comment: Do you mean that for loops are fast for large dataset? That's actually the real reason I have this problem. Looking for solution that is most time-efficient. I feel that if i can do something like `range("b1:b9")=range("a1:a9")+1`, it will be the fastest.

Comment: See the answers here to understand what I really meant by the above comment: *Using Excels inbuilt C++ is the fastest way with smaller datasets, using the dictionary is faster for larger datasets* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044556/quicker-way-to-get-all-unique-values-of-a-column-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for a "time-efficient" solution and avoiding loops are not the same thing.

If you were to loop over the range itself, then yes, it would be slow.  Copying the range data to a Variant array, looping that, then copying the result back to the range is fast.

Here is a demo

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim t1 As Single
    
    t1 = Timer() '  just for reportingh the run time
    
' Get a reference to your range by whatever means you choose.  
' Here I'm specifying 1,000,000 rows as a demo
    Set rng = Range("A1:A1000000")
    dat = rng.Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        dat(i, 1) = dat(i, 1) + 1
    Next
    rng.Value2 = dat
    
    Debug.Print "Added 1 to " & UBound(dat, 1) & " rows in " & Timer() - t1; " seconds"
End Sub
```

On my hardware, this runs in about 1.3 seconds

<sub>FYI, the PasteSpecial, Add technique is faster still</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer. I ran it and it was indeed fast. I'm not so familiar with VBA arrays could you please explain what is this code `dat = rng.Value2` doing? I'm confused that why we can get the value of a range

Comment: `rng.Value2` returns the `Value2` property of the `rng` object, which is a 2D array, of the same size as the range, containing the values of the cells in the range. The reason it's faster is because each operation that accesses a sheet has a time overhead.  Referencing `rng.Values2` is one operation,  looping a range is many operations.

Comment: is the datatype of `dat` created using range.value/value2 is the same as `Dim Array(1 To row, 1 To col)`?

Comment: Data type of `dat` is `Variant`.  If `rng` is more than 1 cell, `Value2` returns a Variant containing a 2D array the same size as rng, where each element is a Variant.

Comment: is there a difference if I just create the array using `dat=Range("A1:A1000000").value2`

Comment: That will get the data into `dat` just fine.  But you won't have a range variable to easily return the result to (`rng.Value2 = dat` in my example)

Comment: oh yes, you are exactly right. I forgot that we will output the value from the array back to the range.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Evaluate, seems quite quick.

```
Sub Add1()

    With Range("A1:A10000")
        .Value = Evaluate(.Address & "+1")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest to fully qualify the range reference and to join (`&`) the range's `.Parent.Name` property plus "!" separator before `.Address`

Comment: Or use Address(External:=True.

Answer (score 0):

Start the macro recorder.

- type a 1 into an empty cell
- copy that cell
- select the cells that you want to add that value to
- open the Paste Special dialog
- select "Add" and OK

Stop the macro recorder.  Use that code as is or work it into your other code.

```
Range("C1").Value = 1
Range("C1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A1:A5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

### Increase Range Values

- In the following examples, the `Add` solution took 2.4s while the `Array` solution took 8.7s (on my machine) to process 5 columns.
- In the `Array` solution, the selection is never changed, it just writes the result to the range.
- The `Add` solution is kind of mimicking this behavior, by setting all selections as they initially were. Hence the complications.

```vb
Option Explicit

' Add Solution

Sub increaseRangeValuesTEST()
    increaseRangeValues Sheet1.Range("A:E"), 1 ' 2.4s
End Sub

Sub increaseRangeValues( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal Addend As Double)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim isNotAW As Boolean: isNotAW = Not rg.Worksheet.Parent Is ActiveWorkbook
    Dim iwb As Workbook
    If isNotAW Then Set iwb = ActiveWorkbook: rg.Worksheet.Parent.Activate
    
    Dim isNotAS As Boolean: isNotAS = Not rg.Worksheet Is ActiveSheet
    Dim iws As Worksheet
    If isNotAS Then Set iws = ActiveSheet: rg.Worksheet.Activate
    
    Dim cSel As Variant: Set cSel = Selection
    Dim aCell As Range: Set aCell = ActiveCell
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = rg.Cells(rg.Rows.Count, rg.Columns.Count)
    Dim sValue As Double: sValue = sCell.Value + Addend
    
    sCell.Value = Addend
    sCell.Copy
    
    rg.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd ' 95%
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    sCell.Value = sValue
    aCell.Activate
    cSel.Select
    
    If isNotAS Then iws.Activate
    If isNotAW Then iwb.Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


' Array Solution    

Sub increaseRangeValuesArrayTEST()
    increaseRangeValuesArray Sheet1.Range("A:E"), 1 ' 8.7s
End Sub

Sub increaseRangeValuesArray( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal Addend As Double)
    
    With rg
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        Dim cCount As Long: cCount = .Columns.Count
        Dim Data As Variant
        If rCount > 1 Or cCount > 1 Then
            Data = .Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = .Value
        End If

        Dim r As Long, c As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = Data(r, c) + Addend
            Next c
        Next r
        .Value = Data ' 80%
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

#1. Disable your autocalculations

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

#2. Disable your screenupdating

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

#3. As long as your row entries aren't more than ~56000, but your dataset is substantial then its quicker to read into an array, do the manipulations in an array, then output that array in one go.

```
array1 = Range(cells(3,2), cells(12,2)).value

for i = 1 to ubound(array1, 1)
    array1(i, 1) = array(i, 1) + 1
next i

range(cells(3,10), cells(12,10)) = array1
```

Note that array1 will be 2D, and you'll be addressing (1,1) through to (10,1) in the example above

Then after pasting back in, reenable your autocalcs, THEN your screenupdate

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```