# Trying to pass (only) unique values from column to dictionary in VBA. Validation not ocurring. What am I missing?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Basically, I want my code to go down through the values in a range and add to a dictionary only unique values. That is, only add the nth value if it has not been previously added. The result being a dictionary which keys are all the values from the range without duplicates. Here's my code:

```
Sub CreatePatientList()

    Dim outputsh As Worksheet
    Set outputsh = Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
    Dim recDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim i As Variant, rowCount As Long
    rowCount = outputsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each i In Range("O2:O" & rowCount)
        If recDict.Exists(i) Then
            MsgBox ("Exists")
        Else
            recDict.Add i, i
        End If
    Next

    Set recDict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Right now, 100% of the values in the range are being added to the dictionary.

Any help? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim i As Variant` is doubly confusing:

- `i` is normally a counter, e.g. a `Long`, in a `For...Next` loop.
- If you're looping through a `Range` with a `For Each...Next` loop, then use a `Range` for your element variable.

So `Dim cell As Range`, for example.

Then, you need to be explicit about the `.Value` of the cell for the key. Currently the *range* is the key, not its value, and since each range is unique, they are all added to the dictionary.

```
Dim cell As Range, rowCount As Long
...
For Each cell In Range("O2:O" & rowCount)
    If recDict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Exists"
    Else
        recDict.Add Key:=cell.Value, Value:=cell.Value
    End If
Next
```

Note that if you just want the unique values (keys), you don't have to check `Exists`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044716/9245853). Also demonstrated in the same answer, it'll be faster to load the data to a `Variant` array first, and then read the array into the dictionary.