# vba find unique values of 3 different columns

Tags: vba, filter

I am trying to find all different values from 3 different columns. The columns' row numbers and everything are different.

Here below you can find my codes;

```
Set r1 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("P22:P" & LastRowXY_1 & "")
Set r2 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("S22:S" & LastRowXY_2 & "")
Set r3 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("V22:V" & LastRowXY_3 & "")

If LastRowXY_1 = 22 Then
    Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(22, 16).Copy
    Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AN1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Else
    r1.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AN1")
End If
If LastRowXY_2 = 22 Then
    Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(22, 19).Copy
    Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AO1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Else
    r2.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AO1")
End If
If LastRowXY_3 = 22 Then
    Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(22, 22).Copy
    Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Else
    r3.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range("AP1")
End If
```

As you can see what I am trying to do is simply get the unique values of the first range "r1" and put them at AN1, then do the same for r2 and r3. And then make a main column by putting that 3 output column in one main column, and use another advancedfilter on that column to create the final result.

But unfortunately, when I do the debug with F8, I see that at output columns, there are duplicate values and that messes up the main output values.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693059/7889129

Comment: How have you initialized the variable LastRowXY_1, 2, 3 etc?