# Excel Create Data Validation Unique items for dynamic Drop Down List without new Column

Tags: excel, list, validation, dynamic, unique

My Table A list which grows on data refresh is as follows:

```
Balham Halfords - P83690
Balham Halfords - P83690
Gloucester & Durham St - P83680
Gloucester & Durham St - P83680
```

In another sheet, I want data validation on the drop down list to show only:

```
Balham Halfords - P83690
Gloucester & Durham St - P83680
```

The trouble is, I don't want to create a distinct list off Table A anywhere in the book, and I want the data validation list to be intelligent to new records coming into to Table A.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any way to accomplish this without helper columns. Data validation (for drop-down lists anyway) is inherently non-intelligent. It only allows you to input a range of cells - does not allow a formula.

Comment: Thank you. I think therefore my best bet is going to be to create a distinct single column table by macro when a new records come in. Then let the data validation list range be the said table. Not ideal though because the users have to click a button when they add to table A and people can't handle these kind of instructions.

Comment: I agree a helper column is needed. Probably could be done with formulas if you want to avoid VBA.

Comment: I posted a new answer that modifies @KresimirL.'s that doesn't use `OFFSET`, which may help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Helper column approach with formula, try this solution.

if your data is in column A, enter this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$900, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$900), 0)),"")` in cell `D2` and drag it down as long as you estimate there will be distinct values. You must enter it using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER since it is an array formula.

[image]

Then use data validation, select list and under source enter this formula `=OFFSET(D2,0,0,198-COUNTBLANK(D2:D200),1)`

[image]

Now whenever new values are added to table, they are also automatically added to your data validation list.
[image]

Comment: Great solution. Didn't know that data validation allowed formulas.

Comment: Thank you, now it intrigues me if it is possible to store the whole array in DataValidation list, removing the need for helper column...?

Comment: Thanks Kresimir. The new array formula works but has made the book really slow. It is recalculating after a new entry comes in and you can see the calculation percentage in bottom right. 

Is the VBA option just to create a unique list for data validation quickly or more sophisticated than this?

Comment: Yes, this array formula tends to slow workbook quite a lot, so it should be used only on small data sets. It is not that hard to create VBA solution for this, try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690814/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-unique-values-from-a-range-in-excel-vba) for more info. You could also create a PivotTable and refresh it each time new rows are added in table...that will eliminate the need for VBA...

Comment: Data validation allows formula, but for some reason UNIQUE doesn't work this would be make it more easier and with no need to create a helper column

Answer (score 0):

@DasalKalubowila, here is a modification on @KresimirL's answer that may be what you're looking for.

First, create a defined name for your input data. Do this by going to **Formulas** on the ribbon and then clicking **Name Manager** under the Defined Names group.

In my example, I called the input data range *InputData*. The formula I used is

`=Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$501,MATCH("Ω",Sheet1!$A$2:$A$501))`

where

- `Sheet1` is the name of the worksheet where the input data lives,
- `$A$2` is the first cell containing data in your input range (I call this the anchor),
- `$A$2:$A$501` is the max area of the column where your data either lives and could potentially live in the future, and
- `"Ω"` is the Omega letter. You can get this by holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and pressing *2* then *3* then *4* on the 10-key number pad (it can also be found in the character map application in Windows).

This formula effectively grows or shrinks your range of data based on how many entries exist.

Next, you need to create a helper column. I know this wasn't desired, but it's going to be one of the only/better ways out there. I placed mine on the same worksheet as my *Input Data*, but you don't have to. The formula I used in `E2` is

`=IFERROR(INDEX(InputData,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:$E1,InputData),0)),"")`

You'll need to commit this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as it's an array formula. Then drag that formula down as far as you to. You'll basically want to go down as many rows as you think you'll have unique entries.

I then needed to create one more defined name, which is what will be used under my **Data Validation** in the next step. I called this new defined name *ValidationList* (this needs to be scoped to the Workbook). The formula I used for *ValidationList* is

`=Sheet1!$E$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$501,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$501,">*"))`

See the notes for *InputData* above to understand this formula better. The only difference is that instead of `MATCH`, this formula uses `COUNTIF`. This is because if your unique values don't yet fill the entire range you dragged your formula down in `Column E` (in the previous step), using `MATCH` in the same way was before would end up grabbing a whole bunch of blanks we don't want. `COUNTIF` therefore only counts those cells that contain a value greater than "*", with asterisk being a wildcard for any character (and "" contains no characters, so it excludes those items).

Now, create your data validation and set it up like such:
[image: data validation example]

Now you should be left with this:
[image: data validation before additional entry]

And when you add information to your *InputData* area, your range of *ValidationList* should expand to include the newest uniques, which in turn will populate inside your **Data Validation** area, like such:
[image: data validation after additional entry]

I find that this doesn't seem to slow my workbooks down too significantly, but I'd be interested in hearing how it performs in yours.

Comment: totsiemae - truly appreciate your  willingness to help. In the end I have opted for light VBA rather than heavier index and match formulae. The user now adds to Table A and runs Macro which creates helper column. The data validation source is now the said column or =INDIRECT("Table5[Description + Code]")

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it will be hard to avoid using a helper column. But if you have MS 365 you can simplify the formula in the Data Validation box to a simple cell reference, using the `#` suffix.

From what the OP says, the data is in an Excel Table `A` which is a good start (and if it is not in a Table, then put it in one!).

If the Table column for is (say) `Name`, then create the helper column formula in cell `F2` as `=SORT(UNIQUE(A[Name]))`

[image]

Then in the Data Validation for cell `D1`:

[image]

**NB:** This setup works best if Calculation is `Automatic`.