# Excel UNIQUE + FILTER table values for data validation drop down list

Tags: excel, list, validation, dynamic

For a certain cell, I´m trying to create drop down list using the data validation function. The contents are coming from a table (queried from a data base).

To replicate the error in its simplest form, I have a table T_raw_data with three Column A, B, and C and I´m trying to create a drop down list using

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(T_raw_data[A];T_raw_data[B]="XXX"))`

The formula has been defined in the Name Manager as "formula_XXX". When referencing the formula in a random cell, I get my desired unique list of filtered values. However when referencing the formula in the data validation of a cell, I get the infamous

> The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?

Is there anyway that works that is not referencing indirectly a cell range where I applied the formula? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use array formula in data validation.  You will need to put the formula in some cells then refer to the cells.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I'll follow the approach here then in case 
anyone is looking for a step-by-step guide. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728066/excel-create-data-validation-unique-items-for-dynamic-drop-down-list-without-new

Comment: As a addendum, while @ScottCraner rightly says you can't use array formulae in the Data Validation and need to use a helper column, you can use the dynamic array notation for the array reference. Eg if helper column cell A1 has the array formula `=SEQUENCE(10)`, in the Data Validation for B1, you can just set the List reference to `=A1#`, rather than use INDEX or OFFSET functions.

Comment: I added an answer to link above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728066/excel-create-data-validation-unique-items-for-dynamic-drop-down-list-without-new/77178764#77178764) which was authored in 2017.