# vba get list without duplicates from listobject

Tags: vba

Is there a vba command to get directly a list without duplicates from the header [autofilter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlVcM.png) of a list object.

My input is [this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So01U.png) and I search a way to get this list without duplicates from my object ListObject in vba

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690814/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-unique-values-from-a-range-in-excel-vba

Comment: Of a non-filtered list?  Or only unique *visible* values?

Comment: I have a non filtered list and would like to get a list without duplicates from my listobject

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: Use a scripting dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this *helper* function:

```
Function GetUniqueValues(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In rng
            .Item(cell.Value) = 1
        Next
        GetUniqueValues = .keys
    End With
End Function
```

to be called by your "main" module as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim uniqueValues As Variant

    uniqueValues = GetUniqueValues(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)

    '... rest of your code
End Sub
```

just change `ActiveSheet`, `ListObjects(1)` and `ListColumns(1)` references as per your needs

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer