# Filter data on basis of one combo box on another combo box

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox

i want to filter data on the basis of value i select from one combo box on another. The image provided is my product master:

[image: Product Master image]

where every product has either same or different color. Both product and color column have combo box in my main transaction page. So, when i select any product from product combo box, all the color of that particular product should only be available in color combo box. [image: Transaction of Product Combo box image]

[image: Transaction of color combo box]

Comment: Please edit your question, include your code attempt to this problem and explain what is not working with your attempt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159428/how-to-filter-data-in-combo-box-vba

Comment: On the `Change` event of your product combobox, construct a filtered array of color based on its value then populate the color combobox `List` with it.

Comment: I'm yet to learn the concept of arrays, if you could simplify it for me, will be very much helpful @RaymondWu.

Comment: @NAITIKJAIN The method in braX's link works as well. Just need to add condition based on the combobox value.

Comment: So i need to add condition on change event of product combo box. Will try it. Thank you.